# migrating to 3.0 from 1.12 - using unbind and click example

Tags: jquery

Is this the correct way to change this when updating to 3.0+ ?

I made the change to see , its working as intended , but i'd like a set of eyes to review being a novice before i change many more similar in this manner.

ORIGINAL

```
$("#MFLChatPopupOverlay").unbind().click(function(){MFLChatPopupClose();});
```

UPDATED

```
$("#MFLChatPopupOverlay").off().on("click", function (){MFLChatPopupClose();});
```

Comment: .off('click').on('click'..

Comment: Change the method call to use .on() or .off(), the documentation for the old methods include specific instructions. In general, the .bind() and .unbind() methods can be renamed directly to .on() and .off() respectively since the argument orders are identical. Why not just .off() ??

Comment: Just `off()` by itself is fine, so long as there's no other event handlers on the element you need to keep. `off()` removes *all* event handlers. `off('click')` removes `click` handlers only. That being said, you shouldn't ever need to bind/unbind event handlers at runtime. It's a bit of a code smell. Use delegated event handlers instead, if this content is dynamically updated.